# Getting an error even after using truncation for tokenizer while predicting (MLM) on bert using huggingface

Tags: python, python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am using `truncation=True` in the tokenizer

```
self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(bert_model_str, truncation=True)
self.pipeline = pipeline("fill-mask", model=self.model, tokenizer=self.tokenizer)
```

however I am still getting multiple warnings

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (556 > 512). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
```

and exceptions

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (697) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

EDIT: Some texts could have mathematical or special symbols. Could they be creating an issue here?

Answer (score 2):

The  [_sanitize_parameters()](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/db7d6a80e82d66127b2a44b6e3382969fdc8b207/src/transformers/pipelines/fill_mask.py#L188) doesn't create `preprocess_parameters` and you can't set `truncation=True` via `from_pretrained`.

But you can override the [preprocess](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/db7d6a80e82d66127b2a44b6e3382969fdc8b207/src/transformers/pipelines/fill_mask.py#L80) method:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, pipeline, BertForMaskedLM
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
pipe = pipeline("fill-mask", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

import types

MAX_LENGTH = model.config.max_position_embeddings

def _my_preprocess(self, inputs, return_tensors=None, **preprocess_parameters):
      if return_tensors is None:
          return_tensors = self.framework
      model_inputs = self.tokenizer(inputs, truncation=True,  max_length=MAX_LENGTH, return_tensors=return_tensors)
      self.ensure_exactly_one_mask_token(model_inputs)
      return model_inputs

pipe.preprocess = types.MethodType(_my_preprocess, pipe)

pipe("[MASK]" +"as "*1000)
```

Output:

```
[{'score': 0.9958381652832031,
  'sequence': 'as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as',
  'token': 2004,
  'token_str': 'as'},
 {'score': 0.0006169977714307606,
  'sequence': 'such as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as',
  'token': 2107,
  'token_str': 'such'},
 {'score': 0.0003573212306946516,
  'sequence': 'an as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as',
  'token': 2019,
  'token_str': 'an'},
 {'score': 0.0003431169898249209,
  'sequence': 'so as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as',
  'token': 2061,
  'token_str': 'so'},
 {'score': 0.0001753663964336738,
  'sequence': 'aj as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as as',
  'token': 19128,
  'token_str': 'aj'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `max_length` parameter along with `truncation=True` so that the tokenizer will truncate within this maximum length. For pretrained Bert, `max_length` should be 512.
From the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/master/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.__call__.max_length).